# Two-way binding an ObservableCollection<string> to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I've been tying different things / reading up on this issue for awhile now and have not yet found an answer. Hopefully you guys can help.

I have an observablecollection of type string. I want to bind this collection to a datagrid and be able to edit/delete/add to the collection. Here is my xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Movies.Titles}"  CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True" Height="300">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The same observablecollection is also bound to a listbox. I want to be able to edit the collection using the datagrid method (above) and see the changes/edits in the listbox. The delete/add is working correctly, but when I edit a string inside a grid cell and it loses focus, the string goes back to what it originally was and never gets updated.

Thanks a lot for any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, I went to do this yesterday and was stuck with a DataGrid that would add a new line for my ObservableCollection. After research, I realized why. Strings and immutable.

I found this question and unfortunately it didn't have an answer. So I can't leave this empty of an answer.

So here are the answers I found:

1. DataGrid cannot update a string collection by adding, editing, or removing strings.
2. I found a workaround to wrap the string in a StringWrapper object. Here it is.

   public class StringWrapper
   {
       public string Text { get; set; }
   }

I didn't like either answer.

The original question asker, moncadad, looks like he wants a one column DataGrid. He probably just wants to add and remove strings from an ObservableCollection without a lot of code. Edit probably isn't too important since that can be done by delete and add again.

I ended up doing this myself with a reusable usercontrol I made called StringListBox.

[A ListBox for strings that supports add and delete](http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/12/20/a-listbox-for-strings-that-supports-add-and-delete/)

Basically the idea is to create the look of a DataGrid with a Label, a ListBox, a TextBox and an Add button and since this is a control, it has to work with ObservableObject or List in one control.

This give you Add and Delete. I doesn't provide edit.

Hope this helps the next guy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works, you should just use

```
Mode=OneWay
```

in your binding.

I hope this helps!

Comment: He explicitly asked for editing support, so this cannot be the solution (can add items, can delete them but cannot edit them). I tell you before someone downvotes it.