# WPF binding datagrid to a string observable collection

Tags: c#, datagrid, bind, observablecollection, itemssource

I've always binded datagrid to observable collection of classes.
Now it should be simpler:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> obcCodes{ get; set; }
```

and then

```
if (obcCodes== null)
    obcCodes= new ObservableCollection<string>();
obcCodes.Add("K2001");
obcCodes.Add("K2002");
obcCodes.Add("K2003");
obcCodes.Add("K2004");
```

after

```
dtgCodes.ItemsSource = obcCodes;
```

so I expected to see those codes in the datagrid instead what I see is:

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe you should to setup DataTemplate for your Items Control to see your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840817/problem-with-two-way-binding-an-observablecollectionstring-to-wpf-datagrid) strings are immutable

so you will have to use

```
    public class StringWrapper { public string Text { get; set; } }
```

and then use it like that:

```
    obcCodes.Add(new StringWrapper() { Text = "K2001" });
```

by doing that you will be able to modify or delete the strings in the datagrid.

Comment: A very trivial add: if you change the class like that  ---> public class StringWrapper {public StringWrapper(string str) { Text = str; }  public string Text { get; set; } } you will be able to add like that ----> obcCodes.Add(new StringWrapper("K2001"));